# Secure File Transfer to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, data-lake

I'm trying to make an architecture for a data lake, I already generated my CSV, txt, and Avro files they are in an On-Premise machine and I want to upload them to Google Cloud Storage, but I see that I have to go through the public internet and I don't want to that.

What options do I have to make as safe as possible?

I was trying to make a Compute Engine environment to upload the files here through  SFTP and then moved them to Cloud Storage, but that will make my cost to  go up.

Comment: What's wrong with the public internet?

Comment: The security team have issues with it, they are afraid that somebody can grab the file in transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this the use case of [Google VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc). The key benefit provided on the product description is:

> For on-premises, you can share a connection between VPC and on-premises resources with all regions in a single VPC

If you look deeper into documentation you may find document [Configuring Private Google Access for on-premises hosts](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access-hybrid). Some information maybe be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options) as well. This might be a good option for you.